# Search Array of strings for matching character sequence

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this

```
const arr = ["Apple", "Banana", "Cherry", "Orange", "Avocado", "Ananas", "Pineapple];
```

I need a function that returns an `array` with all the Elements from `arr`, that match the given character sequence. The order of the characters is of importance.

Given `"ppl"` the function should return `["Apple", "Pineapple"]`.

Given `"n"` the function should return `["Banana", "Orange", "Ananas", "Pineapple"]`.

Given `"voca"` the function shoould return `["Avocado"]`

Given `"rr"` the function should return `["Cherry"]`, while given a `"r"` the function should return `["Cherry", "Orange"]`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a duplicate but I'll just leave you everything that'd be useful:

Check if string includes character sequence:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

Filtering arrays:
https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Combine the two and you're good to go.

Comment: `Given "n" the function should return ["Banana", "Orange"]` it should include `ananas` as well, right?

Comment: @DeepDev Sorry, yes of course

Comment: @Hekmatyar Ah nice, I did not know that there is something like this. I though I need `regex` for that, and that is something I am not able to do.

Comment: When entered `n` , is it expected to return 'Pineapple'? if no, why?

Comment: What about "ey"? Should that also return "Cherry" or is that not supposed to match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```js
const arr = ["Apple", "Banana", "Cherry", "Orange", "Avocado", "Ananas", "Pineapple"];


const search = query => arr.filter(s => s.toLowerCase().includes(query))

console.log(search("n"))
console.log(search("ppl"))
```

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible like this

```
const arr = ["Apple", "Banana", "Cherry", "Orange", "Avocado", "Ananas", "Pineapple"];

const query = 'pp';

arr.filter(element => element.includes(query));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straight forward using filter function and indexOf

```js
const arr = ["Apple", "Banana", "Cherry", "Orange", "Avocado", "Ananas", "Pineapple"];
const cond = 'ppl'
console.log(arr.filter(x => x.indexOf(cond) > -1 ))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function checkPattern(str, pattern) {
    var len = pattern.length;

    if (str.length < len) {
    return false;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
    var x = pattern[i];
    var y = pattern[i + 1];

    var last = str.lastIndexOf(x);

    var first = str.indexOf(y);

    if (last === -1 || first === -1 || last > first) {
        return false;
    }
    }

    return true;
}

var str = "engineers rock";
var pattern = "gin";

document.write(checkPattern(str, pattern));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) combined with [String.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes):

- `const result = arr.filter(el => el.toLowerCase().includes(input))`

Code:

```js
const arr = ["Apple", "Banana", "Cherry", "Orange", "Avocado", "Ananas", "Pineapple"]
const inputs = ["ppl", "n", "voca", "rr", "r"]

inputs.forEach(input => {
  const result = arr.filter(el => el.toLowerCase().includes(input))
  console.log(`Result for ${input}:`, result)
})
```